# Display a status such as sent when a value is null in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, string, null

I am writing a windows forms application in C# for some of our end users, it basically nulls out a value in one of our tables based on a customer account number. I am using a `SqlDataAdapter` to do this which looks something like this:

```
string acct_no = "".Trim();

da3.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand
            ("UPDATE prod.dbo.chartqueue" +
            "SET prod.dbo.chartqueue.sent_datetime = null" +
            "FROM prod.dbo.casemain" +
            "WHERE prod.dbo.casemain.casemain_id = hsmprod.dbo.chartqueue.casemain_id" +
            "AND prod.dbo.casemain.acct_num = @acct_no", cs5);

da3.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acct_no", acct_no);
```

What I would like to do is return a string with a value that says `Sent` or `Failed` depending on whether or not that column returns a null value. Suggestions?

Comment: @MichaelBray: in what sense you mean?

Comment: If you are asking how to return the value of the `sent_datetime` column prior to the `UPDATE` you may want to use the [`OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(v=sql.100).aspx) clause.  You can access the before an after values of any columns.  Aside: It is curious that you chosen to run parts of the SQL statement together without white space where you split the statement across lines.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I see that you have not yet accepted any answers for the 8 questions you have asked.  It is customary to [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) when possible to indicate that a particular answer best solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your query to include in the where clause: `and hsmprod.dbo.chartqueue.sent_datetime is not null`. DataAdapter.Update returns an int which tells you how many rows were updated. If it's zero you know that the field already contained a null, if it's 1, you know the field was not null. You can then do `return rowsUpdated == 0 ? "Failed" : "Sent";` or vice versa depending on what you consider "Failed".